# Как убить горутину, которая долго выполняется

Tags: golang

Есть сторонняя библиотека, которая выполняет некоторую работу doIt() очень долго. Можно запустить выполнение этой функции в отдельной горутине, но вот как прекратить ее выполнение досрочно?

```
func doIt() {
    // очень долго работает
}

func main() {

    result := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        result <- doIt()
    }{}

    fmt.Println(<-result)
}
```

Comment: Дополните вопрос Вашим кодом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если создатели библиотеки не предоставили вам возможность передать в горутину контекст или хотя бы просто канал, то нет. Технически, у горутин есть идентификаторы, но они скрыты от «юзерспейса».